# HTML hiding content in the middle of UL or OL

Tags: html, css

I have long text that gets hidden if it exceeds 300 characters. Hiding is done with a `<span>` that has `style="display:none;"` set.

Basically, after the 300th caracter the rest of the content in wrapped inside that display:none span.

The algorithm is clever enough not to break text in the middle of a tag, so the invisible span will always occur after ending a tag.

The problem I have only happens in Mozilla and that's when the 300th caracter happens to be in the middle of a UL or OL. The rest of the browsers behave properly, hiding the part of the list that's outside the span and showing the other part, but Mozilla doesn't.

Any idea how I can fix this please?

**UPDATE:**
Code:

```
<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li><span style="display:none;">c</li></ul></span>
```

I know it's invalid markup because of the overlapping tags.

Thank you.

Comment: This is way too complex/edge case to not provide code/demo for.

Comment: Seems like Mozilla is just looking for the closing ul or ol tag, and keeps going until it finds it. But you'll have to show us an example to be sure of whats going on.

Comment: Very good point, Josiah.

Comment: Code? Ok... LONG TEXT <ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li><span style="display:none;">c</li></ul></span> ...

Comment: "I know it's invalid markup" -- so why haven't you fixed it?

Comment: invalid markup. there you have your problem. only because other browsers do 'something', does not mean mozilla has to do the same

Comment: Because the <span> is created dynamically. Basically the content which is HTML formatted gets cut off at 300 chars.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your markup. If you properly close the span tag inside the `<li>`, it should work correctly.

```
<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li><span style="display:none;">c</span></li></ul>
```

Closing the `<span>` outside the list may be convenient, but for the browser to properly parse it, you need to use proper markup where possible. If you can't figure out how to close it within the `<li>`, maybe you need to re-think your code.

Comment: Ok, but that would only hide the content of that particular <li> element, and I want to hide everything from there on end.

Comment: You probably want to set the style to hidden for each of the `<li>` elements you want hidden. I know it's messy and painful... :/